# why react app repeat the same console.log output

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, console.log

When I use `console.log` to test my app, it logs the data two times here an screenshot and the code

```
function App() {
const arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
console.log("test");
console.log(arr);
return (
   <p>test</p>
 );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

as you can see I use console.log once for each variable and its log it twice the same thing with error

npm version is 8.19.2

and node v16.16.0

I use npx create-react-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double rendering is caused by [React StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), it only happens in the development environment.

If you want to get rid of it, remove `<React.StrictMode>` that wraps your app. It should be in `src/index.js`

Answer (score 2):

Are you using react 18? This was a new thing added and you should not need to worry about it. When strict mode (only in development mode) is enabled, there will be a second run of the rendering function. This is development-only behavior helps you keep components pure